# Plesk Git Deploy not running "additional deployment actions"

Tags: plesk

Plesk Obsidian offers GIT deployment and we are trying to configure this to work similarly to our previous configuration on CPANEL *(we recently upgraded from a shared account with CPANEL to a VPS with Plesk - Plesk so that we can use Docker later on).*

Here are the details on exactly how we access the GIT configuration on our Plesk panel:

```html
On Plesk Obsidian (Web Pro Edition / Reseller) we access the GIT configuration via:<br>
 --> DOMAINS (left panel menu) <br>
 --> locate desired domain and MANAGE IN CUSTOMER PANEL <br>
 --> open the accordian drop-down for the domain <br>
 --> Git (under DevTools)
 --> (in Git, under DevTools) locate desired repo <br>
 --> REPOSITORY SETTINGS link.
```

The folder structure on the VPS is not optimal, so we attempted to use the MANUAL DEPLOYMENT radio button, under the REPOSITORY SETTINGS link and configure some post-deployment actions - but nothing happens.

In the end, just to prove to ourselves that the manual deployment actions *worked*, we replaced everything we had tried with just this one line:

```
/usr/bin/touch  ./work4me.pls
```

And then searched the file system to see if this file had been created, anywhere. No joy here either (we could not find the file).

Does anyone have any suggestions/ideas on what else to try?

Has anyone used this feature successfully *(i.e. is it probably a configuration problem on our VPS)*?

If the above touch command had worked, where should we be looking for the `work4me.pls` file?

Comment: Same issue here, trying to use /usr/bin/rm and /usr/bin/cp, no success, no feedback. Do you manage to solve this?

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
touch ~/work4me.pls
```

This will create the file on the home directory. I have also tested with other commands as removing contents under a directory and copy them.

```
rm -r ~/folder/*
cp -a ~/source-folder/. ~/folder/
```

Hope this helps!